# Convert SQL Query to play Query Builder Syntax

Tags: java, playframework-2.0

I need help with converting an SQL-Query to something I can use inside play!

The original Query looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `triplestore`
  WHERE `owning_admin_id` IS NOT NULL
  AND `is_public` IS true;
```

My goal is to get something like

```
Triplestore.find.where()
  .isNotNull("owningAdmin")
  .is("is_public", true)
  .findList();
```

Is this even possible or do I have to use JPQL? What would that Query look like?

Thanks in advance,
Hagen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `and()` method:

```
Triplestore.find.where().and(Expr.isNotNull("owningAdmin"),Expr.eq("is_public", true)).findList();
```

Don't forget to add the `com.avaje.ebean.Expr` import.

Answer (score 0):

In Hibernate Criteria:

```
List<Triplestore> triplestores = 
    (List<Triplestore>) session.createCriteria(Triplestore.class)
    .add( Restrictions.isNotNull("owning_admin_id") )
    .add( Restrictions.eq("is_public", Boolean.TRUE) ).list();
```

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

You said *"something I can use inside play!"*, so I'm assuming any third party library is OK. Here's a solution using [jOOQ](https://www.jooq.org) (disclaimer: I work for the vendor).

I'm assuming you're using jOOQ's code generator here:

```java
Result<TriplestoreRecord> result =
ctx.selectFrom(TRIPLESTORE)
   .where(TRIPLESTORE.OWNING_ADMIN_ID.isNotNull())
   .and(TRIPLESTORE.IS_PUBLIC)
   .fetch();
```